# Appending a string to string array (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I'm trying to create a string array that has a certain string `length(vector)` number of times

This is what I have so far:

```
for idx = 1:length(vectorName)
   str(idx) = 'someStr';
   strArray = [str];
end
```

How do I append each string to the string array?

I want the result to look something like:

```
strArray = ['someStr','someStr','someStr',...]
```

where the number of repetitions is equal to the length of the input vector.

EDIT

To give an example:

```
someVector = [1 1 1 1 1];
string = 'someStr';
```

I want the result to be an array of string that looks like this:

```
strArr = [someStr someStr someStr someStr someStr];
```

so that the size(strArr) equals size(someVector)

Comment: That's what `repmat` is for: `strArray = repmat(str, 1, length(vector))`

Comment: Hi @Dan you have multiple of your questions still open without an accepted answer.When a answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you're really asking for is a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of strings where each cell is a copy of the string you want.  You would have multiple copies of this string with each element of a cell being one copy of this string.  If you want to get your code working, you would have to initialize `strArray` to be an empty cell array at the beginning of your code, then append the strings at each iteration in the loop to this cell array:

```
strArray = {};
str = 'someStr';
for idx = 1:length(vectorName)
   strArray = [strArray str];
end
```

Take note that your `str(idx)` statement inside your loop is superfluous and isn't needed.  Just declare it once before the loop, then allow the string to be appended inside the loop.  However, using [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) is the better way to go:

```
strArray = repmat({'someStr'}, 1, length(vectorName));
```

... and an even more simpler way to do it is to ensure that `strArray` wasn't declared in the beginning of your code, then automatically allow MATLAB to create a cell array with as many cells as there are in `length(vectorName)` and slice into the cell by assigning each cell to be the same thing:

```
strArray(1:length(vectorName)) = {'someStr'};
```

Comment: `repmat` is definitely better.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your guys' answers

Comment: Just one question. When I do this:

strArray = repmat('someStr',1,length(vectorName)),

the length of strArray equals the number of elements inside strArray multiplied by 7. 

For example, if there are 8 string elements in strArray, when I run length(strArray) it gives me "56".

Is there something wrong with my code? or is that how repmat automatically works?

Comment: @Dan - That's how I understood your question.... you said you wanted `someStr` to concatenate `length(vectorName)` times.  Concatenate here means to glue strings together.  The loop code and the `repmat` code are doing the same thing.  `repmat` **repeats** a matrix a certain number of times.  In this case, we are repeating this vertical one time, and horizontally `length(vectorName)` times.  This gives you the same output as if you used the loop code.

Comment: @rayryeng, thanks for your reply. 

If I want length(strArray) to equal the number of elements inside the strArray, I should not use repmat but use something else?

Comment: In other words, if vectorName has 10 elements, I want strArray to have 10 elements also

Comment: @Dan - OK... do you want an array where each value `strArray[i]` for `i = 1...length(strArray)` to be an instance of `str = someStr`?  I'm sorry to keep asking you questions, but what you're asking for isn't clear.

Comment: @rayryeng - sorry for not being clear. I just edited my original question and added an example. Thanks so much again for your time

Comment: @Dan - I think you want a cell array.  Try doing: `strArray = repmat({'someStr'}, 1, length(vectorName));`.  This will give you `strArray` matching in length with `vectorName`, but you would need to access each string by `strArray{i}` --> Note the curly braces.

Comment: @rayryeng - thanks so much! it worked exactly as I envisioned

Comment: @Dan - Wicked.  Let me update my answer to reflect this.  If you don't mind, I'd love if you accepted my answer too :)

Comment: @rayryeng I want to note that you cannot **append** element to a Matlab string (char vector/array to be more exact). While append means "add to the vector" in most programming languages, concatenate does just mean that you create a vector which consists of two or more vectors added at the end of the former.

Comment: @patrik - My answer has significantly changed since that point.  I'm no longer dealing with character arrays, but cell arrays.

Comment: @rayryeng Well done! I had totally misinterpreted the question

Comment: @LuisMendo - So did I.  I believe there was a misunderstanding of the vocabulary used, which led me to the confusion.  BTW, thank you :)

Comment: @rayryeng Ok, I see. Sorry for that.

Comment: @patrik - No problem at all.  Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Dan - Please consider accepting my answer if I have helped you.  That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down arrows.  Good luck!